# Can't create the shape I want in drawio

Tags: draw.io

I am trying to make a simple custom triangle shape in draw.io. Unfortunately, there is something very fundamental that I don't understand.

The first image shows the XML I used to create the image. Note that a *preview* shows the offset from (0,0)

The second image shows the triangle after I place it.  Note the offset from (0,0) is real, and the box around it is unexpected - I expected a 40x20 box.

How do I remove the 10 pixel offset and also tighten up that bounding box?

This is where I make it:

[image: This is where I make it]

And this is where I apply it to a diagram:

[image: And this is where I apply it to a diagram]

Comment: Why don't you use the in-built triangle shape in draw.io? There you will not find such an offset once you rotate it.

Comment: Part of this is to learn. Part of this is that I want to write code to interpret the diagram and the rotations are a pain.